# React Native conditionally render part of view while input is focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, purely-functional

I have the following scenario.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={ref => (this.input = ref)} style={styles.input} />
      {this.input.isFocused() && <Text>Hello World</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

This actually works fine, but I get the warning:

> MyComponent is accessing findNodeHandle inside its render. render
>   should be a pure function.

How do I conditionally render The text block and avoid this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use component state :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   state = { isFocused: false }

   handleInputFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true })

   handleInputBlur = () => this.setState({ isFocused: false })

   render() {
      const { isFocused } = this.state

      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput 
            onFocus={this.handleInputFocus} 
            onBlur={this.handleInputBlur} 
          />
          {isFocused && <Text>Hello World</Text>}
        </View>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `{this.state.isFocused && <Text>Hello World</Text>}`?

Comment: It's the same thing , I always extract variables from state and props before the return. It is just a convention.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference refs from the render() method. [Read more about the cautions of working with `refs` here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions)

As you can see in the image below, the first time the component mounts, refs is undefined, when I change the text (Which changes the State, which re-renders the component) refs is now available.

[image: This app updates the state on text change of the Text Input and therefore re-renders the component with the proper refs]

An optimal solution would be using state. I was going to post a solution but Freez already did. However, I am still posting this so you know why you should be using state instead of refs.